# UWP - Inherit from Base Page C#

Tags: windows, inheritance, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I'm one of the many windows app developers. I'm sure someone other ran in this problem too. I want to have a base page (c#) where I add methods and use it in some pages without coding it over and over.

I've tried it like this:

Basicpage.cs:

```
public class BasicPage : Page 
{
    public void Test() {

    }
}
```

SettingsPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : BasicPage{
    public SettingsPage () {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

On the bold "**BasicPage**" there are the errors:

Base class of "...SettingsPage" differs from declared in other parts
and
Base type 'BasicPage' is already specified in other parts

Does someone know a solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume `SettingsPage` has a XAML part, which also needs to be derived from `BasicPage`:

```
<local:BasicPage x:Class="MyNamespace.SettingsPage" ...>
    <!-- settings page content -->
</local:BasicPage>
```